# How to handle business exceptions from service layer in struts 2 at only one place

Tags: spring, exception, struts2

I am working with an application involving Struts2 in web layer and Spring in business layer. 
I also have BusinessException class which will be used by all business services to create business related validation failures which must go up to web layer and should be shown to users as validation message(s). 
        I can easily do this by writing in my Action class:

```
      ClientAction extends ActionSupport throws Exception{
         ....
        try{
            clientService.searchClient();
        }catch(InvalidClientSearchCriteriaException e){
              addActionMessage("Invlid Search Criteria");
        }
        ...
```

And similar code in every action class. However i dont want to pollute my action classes with try catch blocks. Instead it would be much better if i can write on try catch block at one place and catch all the exceptions there as BusinessExceptions and create messages /errors from embedded messages/errors in those exceptions. 
          One approach i could think of was to use interceptor or preresult listener.
But I cannot use interceptor like below which catches BusinessExceptions thrown from action classes...

```
    ExceptionInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor(ActionInvocation ivocation,...){              
          try{
                    invocation.invoke();
          }catch(Exception e){
              if(e instanceof BusinessException){
                   ActionSupport as = (ActionSupport)invocation.getAction();
                   String message = extractMessagefromException()//--custom method to extract message embedded in exception.  
               as.addActionMessages(message);
      //-- above will not work result has already been rendered right? and hence it wouldn't matter if i add action messages now.
           }
         }                                               
   }
```

Second approach of using pre-result listener is to add action messages just like above in pre-result listener's method, as result is yet to be rendered and I can safely change that. However I am not sure if pre-result listener will ever execute, if exception is thrown in action ? And even if it does, how i can get the exception object thrown by the action ?

Please let me know any other approach by which i don't have to clutter my classes with try-catch block

Comment: Have you read this: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/exception-configuration.html?

Comment: @Alexandr: What above link describe s  can work if i want to redirect to a single page for all the exceptions. I wnat to do reverse..i.e. catch the exception at one place but redirect it to relavent original page i.e., the page from which the action was invoked. Like Struts1 has exception handler ..similar to that i want to implement fro struts2